# Schedule remote file download over FTP and process file in memory with Spring Integration

Tags: java, spring, ftp, spring-integration

I need to download a file from a remote FTP server every day and provide its contents to a class as an InputStream (or at least as byte[]) for further processing. Ideally I should also avoid any disk write.

Can anyone give some advice on how to configure it with an XML or an annotation based configuration?

Answer (score 1):

Spring Integration currently doesn't have a pre-configured adapter to 'stream' a file; it does, however, have an underlying component (`FtpRemoteFileTemplate`) that enables such access.

You can configure the remote file template as a bean (using XML or Java Config) - giving it a session factory etc, and invoke one of the `get()` methods:

```
/**
 * Retrieve a remote file as an InputStream.
 *
 * @param remotePath The remote path to the file.
 * @param callback the callback.
 * @return true if the operation was successful.
 */
boolean get(String remotePath, InputStreamCallback callback);

/**
 * Retrieve a remote file as an InputStream, based on information in a message.
 *
 * @param message The message which will be evaluated to generate the remote path.
 * @param callback the callback.
 * @return true if the operation was successful.
 */
boolean get(Message<?> message, InputStreamCallback callback);
```

Something like this...

```
    final ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    boolean success = template.get("foo.txt", new InputStreamCallback() {

        @Override
        public void doWithInputStream(InputStream stream) throws IOException {
            FileCopyUtils.copy(stream, baos);
        }
    });
    if (success) {
        byte[] bytes = baos.toByteArray());
        ...
    }
```

Or you can pass the input stream directly into your handler in `doWithInputStream()`.

The `FtpRemoteFileTemplate` was added in Spring Integration 3.0 (but the `get()` variant that takes a String rather than a `Message<?>` was added in 4.0).

`SftpRemoteFileTemplate` is also available.