# How to download file via SftpRemoteFileTemplate from endpoint

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-integration, spring-integration-sftp

I have File controller like below;

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/files")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class FileController {

     private final SftpRemoteFileTemplate sftpRemoteFileTemplate;

    @PostMapping("/generate/{exportId}")
    public void generate(@PathVariable("exportId") String exportId) {
        File csvFile = createCsvFile(System.getProperty(JAVA_IO_TMPDIR));
        CsvUtils.write(csvFile, prepareExports(exportId));
        Message<File> message = MessageBuilder.withPayload(file).build();
        String path = remoteFileTemplate.send(message, FileExistsMode.REPLACE);
        //store path to download after etc...
    }


    @GetMapping("/download/{filePath}")
    public ResponseEntity<Resource> download(@PathVariable("filePath") String filePath) {
        //I didn't imagine how can i use it to download response?
        sftpRemoteFileTemplate.get(filePath, stream -> {

        });
    }    
}
```

i can upload to file to my SFTP server by using ; **remoteFileTemplate.send(message, FileExistsMode.REPLACE)**

But i couldn't imagine how to download it by  **sftpRemoteFileTemplate.get** method.

it requires ***InputStreamCallback***, how can i use it to make download response?

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26847113/schedule-remote-file-download-over-ftp-and-process-file-in-memory-with-spring-in it showing how to implement 'InputStreamCallback'

Answer (score 0):

Jus create a `FileOutputStream` and copy the data from the input stream to it. e.g.

`FileCopyUtils.copy(stream, new FileOutputStream(new File("local/path"))`;